# mod_rewrite - htaccess - more than one Parameter

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a URL like this:

> https://example.com/folder/j/i?param1=123&param2=456

I have a physical folder `folder`, everything after `folder` should be GET-Parameters, so I get this in PHP:

```
<?php
$mode = $_GET["mode"]; // j
$type = $_GET["type"]; // i
$param1 = $_GET["param1"] // 123
$param2 = $_GET["param2"] // 456
```

At the moment I tried something like that:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?mode=$1& [L,QSA]
```

I don't get, how do I call more than one Parameter?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `/folder/.htaccess` you can have this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /folder/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?mode=$1&type=$2 [L,QSA]
```

This will route `https://example.com/folder/j/i?param1=123&param2=456` to `https://example.com/folder/index.php?mode=j&type=i&param1=123&param2=456`

Comment: Perfect! Hey, is this `^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$` regex?

Comment: Yes `[^/]+` is negation based pattern, which means anything but a `/`

Comment: So ... its not that hard, as I ever thought! Big Thanks to you!

Answer (score 0):

A better way will be using PHP to [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) GET arguments using "/" as delimiter.

Comment: Can you provide an example?